# Vertically align text with tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

We have a span text inside a div element with taillwindcss, what's is the best way to align the text vertically with the div ?

```html
<div class="h-64 w-64 flex flex-col align-items justify-center">
   <span>Home</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot change the span HTML? This is the documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/vertical-align

Comment: You just need to change class for vertical alignment. Please remove `align-items` and use `items-center` instead. For quick reference for classes, you can always use tailwind cheat-sheet.
https://tailwindcomponents.com/cheatsheet/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://www.unpkg.com/tailwindcss@1.9.6/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="h-64 w-64 flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
  <span>Home</span>
</div>
```